# RoutingError Page 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an exception `ActionController::RoutingError` when the user tries to access a non existing route. How can I redirect the user to the 404.html page or render an error on that page?

e.g: when I try to access https://github.com/someuser I get a 404 page on that URL.

I've tried this in application controller with no success:

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do |exception|
  render '/public/404.html'
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4444-can-no-longer-rescue_from-actioncontrollerroutingerror) problem. You should have a look at the comments posted there, especially [this](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4444-can-no-longer-rescue_from-actioncontrollerroutingerror#ticket-4444-5) one by Jose Valim.

Edit: [This](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution) seems to be a better solution, and compatible with other Rack middlewares.

Comment: Thansk. I had tried the Jose Valim solution but it didn't work. It worked with the solution in that blog post. thanks.